# Fullcalendar wrong time in on click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timezone, fullcalendar

I'm using angular and fullcalendar. I have (surprise) timezone-issues, and I can't seem to get it right.

If in the weekview I click on 08.00 hours, I open a modal and show the time, I see 09.00 hours.

```
timezone: "Europe/Brussels",
ignoreTimezone: false,
```

This is (atm) a +0100 timezone, and during summer a +0200 timezone

The click-event:

```
dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {

    $scope.newEventDate = date;

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'newRosterEvent',
        controller: 'NewEventModalController',
        backdrop: "true",
        resolve: {
            event: function () {
                       return $scope.newEventDate;
                   },
            stage: function () {
                       return $scope.stage;
                   }
            }
       });
```

To display the time:

```
stagewebApp.controller('NewEventModalController', ["$scope", "$modalInstance","$filter", "event", "stage", function ($scope, $modalInstance, $filter,event, stage) {

    $scope.stage = stage;

    $scope.day = new Date($filter('date')(event._d, "yyyy-MM-dd"));

    $scope.start = event.toDate();

    ....more code....
}
```

In this case $scope.start displays the clicked time +1

So it seems that fullcalendar takes the time I clicked and converts it to the timezone selected, but I would expect it to interpret the clicked time as being in the timezone I selected.

Apparently I am tackling this wrong, so what is the correct way to do this? ( `$scope.start` should show the time I clicked (preferably in my timezone)). Afterwards I send it to the server where it is stored as UTC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current version of FullCalendar uses [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) extensively.  The problems you are describing are from improper use of `moment` objects.  Specifically:

```
$scope.start = event.toDate();
```

When you call `toDate`, you get back a regular JavaScript `Date` object - which will be based on the same UTC instant, but will *always* take on the behavior of the time zone where the code is running.  You have a few options:

- You can keep it as a `moment` object:

  ```
  $scope.start = event;
  ```
- You can format it to an ISO string that retains the time zone offset:

  ```
  $scope.start = event.format(); // ex: '2015-03-04T08:00:00+01:00'
  ```

With either option, you'll need to follow through with the *usage* of `$scope.start` to expect either a `moment` or a string, rather than a `Date`.

Also, in this code:

```
$scope.day = new Date($filter('date')(event._d, "yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

You should never access the `_d` property directly, as there can be unintended side-effects.  Consider the underscore to mean "internal".  Also, you don't need Angular's date filter here since moment objects have formatting capabilities.  Instead, just do this:

```
$scope.day = event.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```