# moments, dates and datetime-local

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Im trying to override the `fullCalendar` `ClickEvent` and take the start and end date `moment`'s to populate a `<input type="datetime-local"`

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: false,
        droppable: true,
        //edit existing
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
             var startDateString = calEvent.start.toDate().toISOString();
             $('#startDate').val(startDateString.replace('Z', '') );
```

I implemented the above after some extensive research on what exactly this [the below snippet] is expecting when the value is set ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28867755/530933) and [here](http://encosia.com/setting-the-value-of-a-datetime-local-input-with-javascript/))

`<input type="datetime-local" name="startDate" id="startDate" class="ui-widget-content" style="width:100%"`>

However the above always gets the time wrong due to timezones and because im using `toDate()` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28867755/530933)). 
example: I click on an event which shows it starts at 9:30 am, but the input box gets set to 2:30 pm.  How can I probably form my date so that the times are the same when they appear in my input box?

FYI:

I have tried using just `calEvent.start.format()` however my input will not accept it as a valid value (nothing is set in the control, same as whats seen below in the image showing End Date).  I believe this is because instead of "T" separating date and time it is "A" or "P" separating it.

I have tried using `datetime` (instead of `datetime-local`) but as far as I can tell this is just a text box.  `datetime-local` has arrows and separators.  The below image shows the difference, Start Date is `datetime` and End Date is `datetime-local`

[image]

Comment: You are using a jQuery plugin, right? Maybe you should note that in the title and/or tags of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cal events which showed where generated by me doing:

```
    var technicianSchedule = {technician:technicians[Math.floor((Math.random() * technicians.length))] , start:datetimeStart , end:datetimeEnd, title: "Title "+i,description: "Desc "+i};
    technicianSchedules.push(technicianSchedule);
```

I needed to call `.toLocaleString()`on the date objects to remove the timezone stuff

```
    var technicianSchedule = {technician:technicians[Math.floor((Math.random() * technicians.length))] , start:datetimeStart.toLocaleString() , end:datetimeEnd.toLocaleString(), title: "Title "+i,description: "Desc "+i};
    technicianSchedules.push(technicianSchedule);
```